# Spawn mob from other mods

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm looking for a way to spawn entities from other mods. I found that for blocks and items there are a way to fetch them with

```
GameRegistry.findBlock()
```

but didnt found anything similar for mobs. I also didnt found any similar at forge off documentation. Is there any references/guides about communications with other mods?

I'm using MC 1.7.10/Forge 10.13.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of code diving it looks like you can use `EntityList.createEntityByName(String, World)` to create an instance of an entity (it will return null if there's no entity with that name or another error occurs.) If you need to get an entity class from the name you can use the `EntityList.stringToClassMapping` map. Because 1.7.10 doesn't include any generics you'll have to manually cast the returned value from that map. As far as I can tell the type of the map is `Map<String, Class>`, as you probably already guessed.